# Can we have margin for a TEXT report in JASPER defined per line without a page margin or width

Tags: jasper-reports

We are using Jasper to generate a TEXT report which will be used by a PRINTING SYSTEM to print the report. We are able to successfully generate a report but we need the margin or a line break to appear based on each line and not take the default page margin. It should not be using the page margin which is fixed per report . We also tried to use the property  trim.line.right setting to TRUE which does remove the entire right spaces and does left shift the line margin. But we need some space to be padded to the right per line based on the attribute.

Is there a way to disable the page margin or a property to set which overrides the default page margin for a TEXT report . Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks